# Mathematica FindMinimiumPlot not work for 2D case

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica.  I am using version 10.0.1.0. I am trying to do is to follow the examples on the UnconstrainedOptimization.pdf.

I typed in the following lines and got the error message.

```
FindMinimumPlot[Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + Sin[x^2 + y^2], {{x, 2}, {y, 1}}]
FindMinimum::ivar: {{-0.3},{0.5}} is not a valid variable. >>
FindMinimum[{{Cos[0.9 + x^2] + Sin[0.09 + x^2]}, {Cos[1.5 - x^2] + 
Sin[0.25 + x^2]}}, {x, 2}, {{{-0.3}, {0.5}}, 
...........
```

Anybody out there can tell me what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Re: [Introduction to Unconstrained Optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationIntroduction.html)

It looks like you had `y` set to `{{-0.3}, {0.5}}` before you ran the function.

```
Clear[y]
```

or start in a fresh session:

```
Quit[]
```

Then try again.

```
<< Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`

FindMinimumPlot[Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + Sin[x^2 + y^2], {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}]
```